# Can I create some sort of Attachment column in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column, custom-list

User needs a list to track issues. They also want to be able to attach a document to this issue. If this attachment was mandatory I would be able to create a document library, but since it is not I can use a Custom List.

Is there any way I can create an "Attachment" column in a list?

Thanks,
Ninel

Comment: Once the attachment is received, is there a way to move the attachment to a document library for storage. I also need to rename the document for filing purposes

Answer (score 20):

Create custom list, and then enable attachments from **List Settings** -> Advanced Settings.

[image]

This will automatically add a column of [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype.aspx) **Attachments** to the list. But there is no way to have two columns of such type in a list.

Comment: The attachments from List Settings is what I was missing. Thanks...Where exactly is this setting?

Comment: List Settings --> Advanced Settings (under General Settings category). I've updated the post with the screenshot.

Comment: Under the advanced settings in list settings

Comment: what if the attachment option doesn't even show up under List Settings -> Advanced Settings?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no attachment column type.  You have a few options:

1) Simply use list attachments.  No way to make them required, but they are there.

2) Use InfoPath.  In an InfoPath form you can add an attachment field that allows a user to embed their attachment in the form (doesn't go to a SharePoint column, would need to open the InfoPath form to view the attachment).

3) Use a document library.

Comment: What do you mean by list attachements? I'm sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: On your list, go to List Settings > Advanced Settings.  You can enable Attachments there.  Then when editing or creating a new list item, you will have a button to attach to the record.

Answer (score 3):

If you have enabled attachments, you can see "Attach File" option in the ribbon bar when you click on "Add New Item". You can attach file by clicking this button. See below screen shot for reference.

[image]

Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling attachments has already been covered. You also asked how to copy attachments to a SharePoint document library. You can accomplish this using Microsoft Flow. There's a tutorial on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQFTmWOHe8k).