# Sharepoint 2013: no attachment column available

Tags: 2013, list, column

I am having the same issue as [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/can-i-create-some-sort-of-attachment-column-in-a-list), but I have no "list" option in the ribbon, and therefore no "list settings" option.  I am working on a list, but I am baffled by why there is no "attachment" column available.  Attachments are enabled. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure it is a list an not a library? If so the node is called "Library settings"

Comment: Does your list ribbon appear on other lists? This may sound silly, but i'm assuming you have the correct permissions to edit the list?

Answer (score 1):

There must be a Lists option near item option in the Ribbon.
Try following approach:

1. Sometimes ribbon options are not showing as soon as you open the list. So, open the List and select any item created in the list and ribbon will be shown.
2. If list is created by someone else, Check the permissions you are having on the list.

For attachments:

1. Modify the list view and select attachments column to show which list items are having attachments. In list view only paper pin will be shown against item.
2. To see or download these attachments you need to open the respective item(View Item).

Comment: does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Attachments enabled, then go to Modify View and select Attachments to see them. Attachments are usually enabled by default.

Attachments is one of the columns that is automatically added to a list based on settings (like version) so you cannot add or remove it in the list settings.