# Add attachments to Picture Library images?

Tags: attachments, picture-library

Is there any way to add attachments directly to items in a Picture Library?

*(or display items with attachments in a list of image thumbnails, similar to a Picture Library?)*

I've seen [this about enabling an Attachments column for list items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/can-i-create-some-sort-of-attachment-column-in-a-list), but there's no "attachments" section under Advanced Settings.

I've tried a workaround with a Lookup column pointing to items in a second library, which do have attachments, but it's clunky and mucks up search results (every item appears twice in standard search). I've also tried creating a custom content type, but I can't find a way to give this thumbnails without making it unable to have attachments.

---

What I'm trying to create seems very simple - a library, where:

- Each item has a thumbnail image
- The library can be browsed by scrolling a list of thumbnails
- Each item has one or more file downloads, of any file type

...but I can't find any way to do it short of a lookup between two items in two libraries for each thing. I can't find any way to add attachments to items in a Picture library, and I can't find any way to browse by thumbnails in lists where items can have attachments.

---

I don't currently have access or permission to tinker with the underlying code, so UI-based answers would be very much preferable.

---

**Update:** The closest I could get was making a **list** based on a discussion board (which allows attachments - I can't find a way to get attachments on anything based on documents), then adding a column of type "publishing image". This kinda worked - but I couldn't find any way to get this column's images to always display like thumbnails at a set size. There's an option to set either width or height with fixed aspect ratio for each image for each item, but a) I couldn't find any way to set a default, so we'd rely on users remembering to apply a setting, and b) since only one of width or height could be set, a tall and thin image or short and fat image would disrupt the thumbnail list. I believe it's possible to fake thumbnails using formulas in calculated columns... but that's wayyyy beyond my current ability level, I'm struggling to follow the steps in [tutorials](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2010/03/06/need-a-thumbnail-field-in-the-document-library-for-the-uploaded-picture-then-read-this-post.aspx) I've found (any help would be gratefully received!).

Comment: Have you tried using a document library with a picture field as one of the columns to use as a thumbnail?

Comment: When you say picture field, do you mean as a column on the library, or as a field on the content type, or something else? I've tried lots of things like that. I'll edit the closest I got into the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the easiest way to do this would be through XSLT (data viewer webpart) or custom Javascript. I can't think of a way OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

The Library creates a thumbnail image for you just with upload the image, the address to access these thumbnails is:

http:///library/folder/t/imagename

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I've seen this about enabling an Attachments column for list items, but there's >no "attachments" section under Advanced Settings.

What version of SharePoint are you using? You should be able to enable attachments to a Custom list as the referenced article describes. If you can't do that, then something odd is going on, and I don't see how you'll be able to go much further with your problem.

Note: I would have added this as a comment, but apparently I need 50 points or more here in order to do that.