# Import Excel spreadsheet with attachements to SP 2013 list

Tags: attachments, database-attach

I have a SharePoint Site which I want to import my Excel spreadsheet.

I know how to import the Excel sheet, but a lot of the records in my old application have attachments to them, so is there a way to import them and still have the attachments go along with them?

Below is the example of the records and the attachments that I want also when I import the record to SharePoint.

[image]

Comment: Matt, are you trying to just save the entire workbook to a document library? Or do you need extra data into SharePoint columns?

Comment: I will import the workbook in to a sharepoint list, but a lot of the records have PDF attachments affiliated with them, how would I bring in those attachments with the records that contain them?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a SP List. I'd first try to upload the file to a document library and see if the attachments stay intact. From there, you can figure out what to do with the data you need from it.

Comment: Wow. That's not going to work. Too labor intensive with so many attachments.

Let me get this straight...you've already got the spreadsheet importing properly...you're just trying to figure out how to manage the gazillion attachments, right?

Comment: Are you wanting to store them separately, like in a document library folder? I think it would be cleaner that way you could just link to the attachments folder for that record.

Comment: Yes that is fine, but how do link them while I do the export ?

Comment: You're first going to create the record and come up with a name for the attachments folder, which will be saved in a column. You'll then create the folder for the attachments and drop all the files. You'll need to develop an application page or web part that will display the links to the attachment files in that folder for the record selected.

Comment: Do you know where there is a script that does a similar function?

Comment: No. I will take a quick look

Comment: Just thought of another option. You can change the advanced settings to accept attachments for the list. see here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/can-i-create-some-sort-of-attachment-column-in-a-list

I would zip everything and just attach it to the list item.